# Contentful with React / Redux, best practices for retrieving data

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, redux, contentful

I'm using Contentful as a CMS for my personal website built with React / Redux and I'm a little confused on how to deal with the async fetching of data.

For my site, I have a `Blog` view that lists my `BlogPost`s and clicking on one would take you to the `BlogPost` view. In both these components, I want to animate in those elements when they are fetched / loaded.

I have 2 solutions in my head to handle fetching and animating:

1. My current solution is in the root `App.jsx` to fetch all the posts from Contentful on `componentDidMount()` and populate the Redux store key, `posts`. This will be the only API request to Contentful. Then in the `BlogPost` component I would handle things like so:

BlogPost.jsx

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.posts.length > 0) { this.animateIn() } 
    else { show loading spinner }
}

componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.posts.length > 0) { this.animateIn() }
}
```

This way I can handle if the user goes to the BlogPost page from the Blog page or if they refresh on a BlogPost page.

2. Second solution is one that I'm seeing in several online examples like [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-blog?file=components%2Fmodal.js). Instead of one API request, the example makes multiple requests. So in my `BlogPost` component, on mount I would make a request to get the specific post and then populate. This way, I don't repeat code in both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` but it's adding more API calls.

I'm leaning on sticking with my current solution but I was wondering if any experienced Contentful (or really any CMS users) have any opinions on best practices for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to make a request for the individual blog posts in the `BlogPost` component, otherwise it would be impossible to visit individual blog posts directly without going through the `Blog`view.

You still need to fetch for all blog posts in the `Blog`component to display the list. But since you don't need to display the whole blog post in the list you can minimize the size of the request by only fetching for things you need, like title and id of the posts. (Not sure if that's possible with the contentful api though)

Also I'd recommend moving the data fetching into a container component, which makes for a bit of cleaner/better structured code. [This article](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) explains that concept of container components pretty well.

Comment: Hm I can visit individual blog posts directly because the wrapper App.jsx makes the GET request for all posts

Comment: Ahh okay. But in that case you're requesting way more data than you actually need, that doesn't scale well if you eventually have a lot of posts. So I'd still go for the second solution.